# Is there a way to download Python for Visual Studio on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio

Needless to say I'm not very good at setting up IDEs yet. I have about four different projects I'm working on right now and I decided I'd like to have some mobility by being able to take my MacBook around and still code with it away from my PC.

Setting up Visual Studio on my PC was really simple. It had a checklist of extensions/developer languages to choose from at install and Python was right there. Fast forward to installing it on my MacBook and it pretty much has C#, F#, and that's it.

Am I missing something obvious like Python doesn't work on MacOS?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the replies! I looked into extensions and that still ended up being a dead end. I did notice that you two mentioned VS ***Code*** while I was strictly looking at the VS IDE. Turns out the Mac version of VS IDE does not support Python from install while the Windows version does. Either way at this point I'm going to use Eclipse haha.
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/#vs_mac_table

Answer (score 2):

It 100% should be available. You should be able to install it directly from the *Extensions* tab. If you don't find it, here's a video I found that goes step-by-step through setting up VSCode for Python on MacOS : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06I63_p-2A4

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should be downloadable. Just go to the extensions tab and install python from there. Python should work in VS Code Mac.